# How to process ajax success data's first value differently than the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Consider the following code:

```
'use strict';
$.getJSON('/img/content/galleries/', function(directories) {
    $("#gallery").text("");
    for (var dirnum = 2; dirnum < directories.length - 1; dirnum++) {
        (function(dirnum) {
            var folder = '/img/content/galleries/' + directories[dirnum] + '/';
            $.ajax({
                url: folder,
                success: function(data) {
                        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
                            if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                                $("#gallery").append('<a class="fancybox-thumb" href="' + folder + val + '" rel="fancybox-thumb"><div class="gallerypictures" style="background-image:url(' + folder + val + ')"></div></a>');
                            } // end val.match
                        }); // end data.find
                    } // end success
            }); // end ajax
        })(dirnum); // end closure
    } // end for loop
}); // end getJSON
```

What it does is simply retrieving the sub directories of the "galleries" folder and then via an ajax call, get the file names and output the content of each sub directories (gallery1 and gallery2 for example) in alphabetical order to the #gallery div.

This code works fine as is and outputs all the files properly. Here is what I am missing:

I would like for each subdirectory, to process the first image differently than the others (I simply want to add a class to the first image of each subdirectory).

I am pretty new at this ajax business so I'm a bit confused how to filter the first image of each subdir. Or perhaps there is an easier way to think about this?

Thanks in advance!

Erick P.

Answer (score 0):

in your callback on the find function use an if statement like:

```
$(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
  if(i === 0){
     // whatever you want to do to first element in here

   } // end val.match
});
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it's not working. I checked the values of i and val and what I get is:

i: 0 to 10 (2 times - 11 values for each subdirectories of 6 images..)

val:
?C=N;O=D
?C=M;O=A
?C=S;O=A
?C=D;O=A
then the path to "galleries"
then the name of the 6 images from gallery1 (one by one)

then I get the same thing again but now with the gallery2 filenames at the end...I'm even more puzzled now..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding variable `i` at `for` loop , passing `i` to IIFE , using `if` condition to check for `i` being equal to `0`

```
for (var dirnum = 2, i = 0; dirnum < directories.length - 1; dirnum++, i++) {
    (function(dirnum, i) {
        var folder = '/img/content/galleries/' + directories[dirnum] + '/';
        $.ajax({
            url: folder,
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(_, val) {
                    if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                        if (i === 0) {
                          // do stuff
                        }
                        $("#gallery").append('<a class="fancybox-thumb" href="' + folder + val + '" rel="fancybox-thumb"><div class="gallerypictures" style="background-image:url(' + folder + val + ')"></div></a>');
                    }
                    // end val.match
                });
                // end data.find
            }// end success
        });
        // end ajax
    })(dirnum, i);
    // end closure
}
```

Comment: When I add your code it doesn't output any images anymore. I've never used jsfiddle in the past but I think my example would be hard to recreate as it involves getting the initial data from php. Have you seen my comment below on the output I got from the i and val vars? Any blinking ideas there?

Comment: See updated post. Is requirement to check for first `$.ajax()` call ?

Comment: this is getting close. Now it is processing all images from gallery1. What I really need is the first image of gallery1 and then the first image from gallery2...geez this is not easy!

Comment: Try changing condition within `if` to `if ($("#gallery a".length === 0 || $("#gallery a".length === 1))`